# Iterate and replace NaN values with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Reading similar posts but don't seem to find the right solution - I'm trying to replace NaN values in a dataframe with the correct ones in a new dataframe. While I'm trying to iterate over the dataframe, I'm running into some errors.

```
masterdataframe

    |Date      | Key | Column1 | Column2 | Column3
 0  |2020-12-22| A   | 123     | 345     | 678
 1  |2020-12-22| B   | 123     | 345     | 678
 2  |2020-12-23| C   | NaN     | NaN     | NaN
 3  |2020-12-24| A   | NaN     | NaN     | NaN
 4  |2020-12-25| B   | NaN     | NaN     | NaN
```

The dataframe with the data that I need looks like the following:

```
df1
    |Date      | Key | Column1 | Column2 | Column3
 0  |2020-12-23| C   | 123     | 345     | 678
```

How would I iterate over masterdataframe to replace the correct rows with the data in df1? Currently I'm doing the following:

```
 for ind, row in masterdataframe.loc[3:].iterrows():
      masterdataframe[column1][row] = df1.iat[0,2]
      masterdataframe[column2][row] = df1.iat[0,3]
      masterdataframe[column3][row] = df1.iat[0,4]
```

However I'm getting the following error: "ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values"

What's the best solution for me to ensure that I'm inserting the values from df1 into the correct row for the masterdataframe?

My ideal output would be the following:

```
masterdataframe

    |Date      | Key | Column1 | Column2 | Column3
 0  |2020-12-22| A   | 123     | 345     | 678
 1  |2020-12-22| B   | 123     | 345     | 678
 2  |2020-12-23| C   | 123     | 345     | 678
 3  |2020-12-24| A   | NaN     | NaN     | NaN
 4  |2020-12-25| B   | NaN     | NaN     | NaN
```

Appreciate the help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.update` to update all the values in masterdataframe with the values from df1. To do that you will need to set index to the Key column in both dataframes.

```
masterdataframe = masterdataframe.set_index('Key')
df1= df1.set_index('Key')
masterdataframe.update(df1)
```

This will update the values in masterdataframe with the values from df1 for all the columns where Key in masterdataframe = Key from  df1 and the column names are identical.

Depending on what you want to do after that, you may want to reset the index:

```
masterdataframe = masterdataframe.reset_index()
```

Comment: How would I use this solution if I have multiple rows with the same Key but different dates? Wouldn't this solution update the rows with the wrong date?

Comment: If you need to bring the values over based on combination of Key and Data then set the index to two columns: df1 = df1.set_index(['Key', 'Date']) and masterdataframe = masterdataframe.set_index(['Key, 'Date'])